# Anonymous phone call from Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app (with Angular), I give the ability to the users to call a phone number (using the [Call Number Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number)), in 2 different ways:

1. Either **publicly**
2. Or **anonymously** to mask their phone number, by prepending `#31#` to the callee phone number

No issue for the first case.

However, it doesn't work anymore for the second mode (dialer doesn't even open) whereas it used to work for a long time without any problem.

I also tried from a plain `window.open`:

```js
window.open('tel:#31#XXXXXXXX')
window.open('tel://#31#XXXXXXXX')
window.open('tel:%2331%23XXXXXXXX')
window.open('tel://%2331%23XXXXXXXX')
```

but still doesn't work, either on iOS or Android.

Strangely, this does work from Safari on iOS (not tested on Android):

```html
<a href='tel://#31#XXXXXXXX'>Call me</a>
```

although I have to use `tel://` and not `tel:` to avoid having the following exception: `Failed to launch 'tel:#31#XXXXXXXX' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.`

Has anyone ever experienced the same issue?

Comment: FWIW, prepending `#31#` isn’t guaranteed to work for everyone every time to suppress their number.

Comment: Ok, but IMO that's the least constraining method for the end users, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. **%2331%23XXXXXXXXXX**
2. 

> encodeURIComponent('#31#XXXXXXXX')

%23**31**%23 = #31#

Example:

```html
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer" href="tel:%2331%23XXXXXXXXXX">Anonymous tel:#31#</a>
```

Comment: Tried that as well, same problem.

Comment: Updated example